# What should be the correct logical relation between these tables in Entity Framework 6

Tags: database, relational-database

Could you please tell me what should be the correct association between table EmployeesRoles and Roles? I would like that Each record of EmployeesRoles is assigned to any record of Roles.

Does it mean it is One to Many relation?
Which table is a Dependent in this case?

[image: model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but it appears that you have a Many to Many relationship between `Employee` and `Role` (i.e. there can be MANY employees which can each hold MANY roles).

The `EmployeesRole` table is a linking table, which would normally be handled internally by Entity Framework and not exposed in your class hierarchy.  [see this asp.net article](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/many-to-many-mappings-in-entity-framework).

Incidentally, instead of the table having a primary key of `EmployeeRoleID`, The standard (in both Entity Framework and SQL) would be to have a compound key of both `EmployeeID` and `RoleID`.

Also, there is not a 1..1 Relationship between `Employee` and `EmployeesRole`, unless the `Employee` can only have one `Role`, but if that were the case, this table would be unnecessary.

Comment: You are right! 

"Also, there is not a 1..1 Relationship between Employee and EmployeesRole, unless the Employee can only have one Role, but if that were the case, this table would be unnecessary." 

This table is not necessary and relation should be directly between role and employee. The error is in logic. Thank you!